# czowOiIiOw== being added to empty fields in exp_channel_data

Tags: matrix, php-errors

A client's MSM powered EE 2.6.1 site including Matrix 2.5.5 has just gone live and new entries with empty Matrix fields are ending up with 'czowOiIiOw==' in them – this I understand is a PHP base 64 encoded empty string.

This of course causes template logic that hinges on empty fields to break!

Any suggestions for a fix? I can go into the database and clear 'czowOiIiOw==' but I'd like to do better than that ;)

Comment: Technically, it's an empty array that's been serialized and base64 encoded, but who's counting :-). You say you're using Matrix 2.5.5--I see that 2.5.6 has been released with a few bug fixes. Have you given that a try?

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Just saw your comment after making my post below. Yes it does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P&T recommended an update to Matrix 2.5.6 as a fix for this issue, which is apparently to do with "a small bug with support for EE Revisions".

I confirm that the 2.5.6 update fixes this issue for me.

Comment: Good to hear 2.5.6 fixes it! Kinda takes the fun out of the bug hunt, but I figured if P&T had already fixed the issue maybe you wouldn't want to spend more time on it. :-)